# Disable Sitecore FXM

Tags: experience-editor, fxm

I would like to know what is the best way to disable Sitecore Federated Experience Manager (FXM) in Sitecore 8.1? 
We are not really using any Sitecore's XP features.  One way I know of is to remove the Sitecore FXM folder from APP_Config. 
But I am not really sure if that is the best way. Wanted to see how others do it.

Reason to remove is that there is another exception in the website that is happening because of this module. While I can patch it and fix it - I don't really use and would not need any of those work.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: sorry .. forgot to mention that..it is 8.1. Added that to the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling config files is better option than deleting whole FXM folder.

Just add ".disabled" extension to all config files under App_Config\Include\FXM folder

[image]

Also don't forget to hide Federated Experience Manager from Launchpad for Content Editors:

[image]

as after clicking on this button they will end up in this never ending loop:

[image]

You can do it in "core" db by removing Inheritance for item /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Marketing/Federated Experience Manager:

[image]

Use Security Editor with role that is used by Content Editors (Author is here only as example, button is already hidden for this role):

[image]

Unfortunately for Administrator, this cannot be hidden, so just ignore this button as admin :)

Comment: Thanks @peter-prochazka. I ended up doing most of what you had mentioned. Only difference is, we dont have Sitecore Experience manager license, so never had FXM icon in the first place.  What i did not understand is , why would that get installed or turned on in first place.  But since i joined late, i dont have an answer to that.

Comment: Hi, I was migrating 8.2 to 9.2 and while disabling Sitecore.FXM.config I ended up in an error "No service for type 'Sitecore.FXM.Abstractions.IFxmLog' has been registered."

Comment: I would recommend creating separate question @PVM for this problem as it is not related to this question.